# Can I install a dryer vent low in the outside wall without compromising structural integrity?

Tags: plumbing, dryer, vent, exhaust-vent

I need to vent my dryer as previous owner had it venting inside the garage which caused several lint and humidity problems. Is it ok to drill the 4" hole on the very bottom part of the exterior wall just above the concrete slab? See attached picture.

[image: picture of wall above slab]

Answer (score 1):

Go right through the rim board between the joists and you will be home run.

You certainly don't mean the concrete which of course would rather be more than un-necessary, won't work if is below ground outside if not close to it which won't be proper, get dirt and what not in the vent and so on plus way misrable and nobody wants misery.

Okay, you take care.

Answer (score 0):

I originally thought you were talking about going through the wall above the slab floor but the comments suggest you mean above the top of the wall.  Going through the rim board would not be a problem. Get a 4" hole saw and have at it.

Comment: I think the OP wants to go through the rim board.

Comment: OP said above the concrete.

Comment: @crip659  Above the concrete slab.

Comment: Think bad wording on OP's part.  Can be taken either way.  Most basement slabs are underground.  Picture is pointing to the top of the cement wall.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate  I think you're right, makes more sense.

Comment: @crip659  Yes, confusing

Comment: If it is a gas dryer and it snows in your location consider the likely hood of carbon monoxide build up if the vent were to be buried in snow . Many municipalities now have minimum height above grade for this reason.

Comment: My plan is to drill on top of the slab on the wood side which goes to the backyard. The question is if it's problematic for the wall.

Comment: Thanks it doesn't snow here

Comment: @piotr Drilling the rim board will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Spend some time finding where the studs are if any, also look for water/electrical (not to drill in them). Drilling through the rim board just on top of concrete should be fine.

Get a 4 inch hole saw.

Start with drilling pilot hole (~1/4 inch), to find out where it comes out. You can also use that pilot hole to drill from outside.

If you have stucco on the outside, be aware there is wire mesh that you have to drill true.

Comment: Thanks. The question is if it's ok to drill so low on the wood wall that starts above the slab

Comment: You downvoted my post, so you do not agree with "Drilling through the rim board just on top of concrete should be fine."

Comment: I didn't downvote it. Thank you so much for answering. I think you are absolutely right, and that was my plan from the beginning. Is just that it doesn't answer the question. I will upvote it as an appreciation. Thank you.

Comment: @piotr sorry for missunderstanding,  I thought to have answered the question, and gave you a tip for the pilot hole